# Game code error line skipping - Python

Tags: python

I have this code for a number guessing game and i was playing it when I noticed a problem.

# Guessing the number

```
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20. Can you guess my number?")

r = str(input('{} please enter a integer between 1 and 10: '.format(name)))

r = str(input('{} please enter a integer between 1 and 10: '.format(name2)))

print (name, ' you chose ', r)
print (name2, ' you chose ', p)
r1 = random.randrange(10)
```

## Printing who won

```
if r == p:
    print('Plz choose different numbers from each other')
if r == r1:
    print('Computer chose', r1,',',name,' Wins!')
if p == r1:
    print('Computer chose', r1,',',name2,' Wins!')
elif (r > 'r1' and p < 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
elif (r < 'r1' and p < 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
elif (r > 'r1' and p > 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
elif (r < 'r1' and p > 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
```

When the computer read this part of the code

```
if r == p:
    print('Plz choose different numbers from each other')
if r == r1:
    print('Computer chose', r1,',',name,' Wins!')
if p == r1:
    print('Computer chose', r1,',',name2,' Wins!')
elif (r > 'r1' and p < 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
elif (r < 'r1' and p < 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
elif (r > 'r1' and p > 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
elif (r < 'r1' and p > 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you lose')
```

It skipped the first parts and keep saying that both players lost. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
r = str(input('{} please enter a integer between 1 and 10: '.format(name)))

r = str(input('{} please enter a integer between 1 and 10: '.format(name2)))
```

Don't you mean to assign to `p` the second time through? `p = str(...`

Also, these lines don't make much sense:

```
elif (r > 'r1' and p < 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you loose')
elif (r < 'r1' and p < 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you loose')
elif (r > 'r1' and p > 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you loose')
elif (r < 'r1' and p > 'r1'):
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you loose')
```

You're comparing `r` and `p` to the string `'r1'`. You probably mean to be comparing to `r1` itself, but even then the logic is really strange. I think you just want `if r != r1 and p != r1`, but the below is much simpler:

```
if r == p:
    print('Plz choose different numbers from each other')
elif r == r1:
    print('Computer chose', r1,',',name,' Wins!')
elif p == r1:
    print('Computer chose', r1,',',name2,' Wins!')
else:
    print('Computer chose', r1, ' both of you loose')
```

(Note, though, that the word is spelled "lose.")

**UPDATE**

You probably want integers:

```
r = int(input('{} please enter a integer between 1 and 10: '.format(name)))

r = int(input('{} please enter a integer between 1 and 10: '.format(name2)))
```

Comment: I think there are numerous problems. Here's another: why are we comparing first variables `p`, `r`, and `r1` (`p == r1`) and then sometimes strings `r < 'r1' and p > 'r1'`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yeah, actually just made an edit for that.

Comment: "The word is actually spelled 'lose' though." +1

Comment: Thank you for catching the spelling error

Comment: I tried your simpler code smarx but I am still getting the problem where it is always printing both lose no matter what.

Comment: Oh, I think you want `int(input...)` instead of `str(input...)`. The latter is meaningless, since `input` already returns a `str`, and you want to use a number for comparison.

Comment: That seemed to do it thx